# SonarQube 6.1 Execute Analysis Permissions

Tags: maven, sonarqube, user-permissions, sonarqube-scan

We would like to allow any user to run a SonarQube preview analysis (authenticated or not). However, we'd like to restrict whom can upload analysis to the server.

In order to allow all users to run preview analysis, the documentation indicates that the Anyone user needs access to Browse and Execute Analysis.

However, it seems that running the maven sonar plugin at the command line is still requiring sonar.login and sonar.password.

Additionally, we would like to limit who can upload analysis to only the sonar-administrator group.

Here is a screenshot of our project permissions:
[image: project permissions]

Here is a screenshot of our Global permissions:
[image: global permissions]

Unsuccessful command:

```
mvn -o org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.branch=$BRANCH -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.skipPackageDesign=true -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

Successful command:

```
mvn -o org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.branch=$BRANCH -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.skipPackageDesign=true -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json -Dsonar.login=%SONAR_USERNAME% -Dsonar.password=%SONAR_PASSWORD%
```

Please help me fine-tune our access options so that we achieve the goal of allowing preview analysis but excluding the ability to push analysis.

Here is some excerpts of the failing job. I removed some of the details that are company specific.

```
    > mvn -o org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.branch=$BRANCH -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.skipPackageDesign=true -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
...
[INFO] Performing issue tracking
[INFO] 772/772 components tracked
[WARNING] Console report is deprecated. Use SonarLint CLI to have local reports of issues
[INFO]
-------------  Issues Report  -------------
       +13 issues
        +1 blocker
        +1 critical
        +3 major
        +8 minor
     -------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Export issues to c:\Source\releases\vcmmigrationmgr\vcmmigrationmgr-app\target\sonar\sonar-report.json
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.933 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-25T10:59:46-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 100M/3582M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project vcmmigrationmgr-app: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Edit: I removed "Execute Analysis" from the Anyone permission. I also removed 
"-Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json" from the command. I do not understand why preview mode is requiring a user name and password. Is there any way to allow anonymous users to run in preview mode?

Comment: First, permissions shouldn't be required to run a preview analysis, but beyond that since 'Anyone' has Execute Analysis permissions at both the global and project levels, it's hard to believe this is a permissions issue. Since the error only shows up at the attempt to write out sonar-report.json, are you sure this path is writable?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, the path is writable. However, removing the parameter "-Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json" does allow the analysis to complete!
It sounds like we need to move to the SonarLint CLI in order to get a report?

Comment: If we try the same command with sonar.login, sonar.password, and sonar.report.export.path, the job is successful. Which (to me) indicates that it is indeed a writable path.

I attempted to reduce the permissions on the server. I removed "Execute Analysis" from the "Anyone" user group from all projects. Globally, I removed "Execute Analysis" and "Create Projects" from the "Anyone" group.
We receive a failure when we run without credentials and without sonar.report.export.path. How do I allow all users to execute analysis but not update the server?

Comment: Now that "Execute Analysis" is no longer available to "Anyone", we have have many reports of users trying to use preview mode but it requiring a username and password. If I understand the comment from @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, we shouldn't need sonar.login and sonar.password.